# docker build failed in mac

Tags: docker, go

I have a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in my go project.

It is the contents of Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.7

RUN set -x; \
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; \
  echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise main " >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FF160426C4832F92 \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    libzmq1=4.0.4-bpa~precise1 \
    libzmq-dev=4.0.4-bpa~precise1 \
    pkg-config

ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH
ENV GOPROJECTPATH /go/src/emitter
COPY . $GOPROJECTPATH
WORKDIR $GOPROJECTPATH

RUN go get -v

CMD ["bash"]
```

It is the docker-compose.yml

```
dev:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/go/src/emitter
  working_dir: /go/src/emitter
  command: bash
  net: host
```

When I try building an image by running:

> docker build --tag docker-task .

I have the below error in my terminal

```
[+] Building 4.3s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.7                                                                                         1.5s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.7@sha256:93b2b52f1212e97b6650bde1f20f6a359b08c117c57a848970d615fe88623a3d                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 277B                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN set -x;   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;   echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bpaquet/zeromq4-precise/ubuntu precise ma  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY . /go/src/emitter                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] WORKDIR /go/src/emitter                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN go get -v                                                                                                                         2.8s
------
 > [5/5] RUN go get -v:
#9 0.809 github.com/pebbe/zmq4 (download)
#9 2.680 github.com/pebbe/zmq4
#9 2.754 # github.com/pebbe/zmq4
#9 2.754 runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
#9 2.754 fatal error: newosproc
#9 2.754
#9 2.754 runtime stack:
#9 2.754 runtime.throw(0x5ba65a, 0x9)
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
#9 2.754 runtime.newosproc(0xc42002a000, 0xc420039fc0)
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:160 +0x194
#9 2.754 runtime.newm(0x5d6628, 0x0)
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1572 +0x132
#9 2.754 runtime.main.func1()
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x36
#9 2.754 runtime.systemstack(0x688400)
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79
#9 2.754 runtime.mstart()
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079
#9 2.754
#9 2.754 goroutine 1 [running]:
#9 2.754 runtime.systemstack_switch()
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc420024768 sp=0xc420024760
#9 2.754 runtime.main()
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127 +0x6c fp=0xc4200247c0 sp=0xc420024768
#9 2.754 runtime.goexit()
#9 2.754    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4200247c8 sp=0xc4200247c0
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go get -v]: exit code: 2
```

So my question is what the error about, and how to pass the build.

many thanks

Comment: Did you drop a digit in the first line of the Dockerfile; do you mean `FROM golang:1.17`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the new MacBook with M1/M2 chip?
If yes, then:

- Use this in Dockerfile: `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:1.7`
  OR
- Set `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` enviromental variable

Comment: yes it is `Apple M1`

Comment: Then please try either of the solutions provided above.

Comment: tried both, but sorry still not working, same error. I am reading this post: https://blog.driftingruby.com/docker-builds/, hope it gives me some hint.

Comment: The post that you mentioned is also helpful. But also, it looks like golang image is not built on arm64 architectue [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/tags) . So, please report to the appropriate repository to correct this/enhance the image support.

Comment: yes, if it is the issue I will report, will try the solution from the link above first.